# Audio freeze, buzzing crashes Windows 10 with Blue Screen Of Death

Tags: windows, windows-10, latency

Lately, I have been experiencing multiple blue screens of deaths, game freezes, audio buzzing, complete blackouts of the screen. I have updated to the latest GPU drivers, audio drivers, latest BIOS version but still, I was still unable to resolve any issues.

#### My system specifications:

- **Laptop:** Asus ROG G752VY
- **OS:** Windows 10 PRO 64-bit Version 1903
- **Processor:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60 GHz
- **GPU:** NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX980M with 4GB GDDR5
- **Memory:** 16 GB DDR4 2133 MHz
- **Storage:** 1TB HDD 7200 RPM && Windows OS installed on Samsung 960 Evo 256GB

More info on the specifications of the laptop [available here](https://www.asus.com/uk/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G752VY/specifications/).

I decided to run [LatencyMon](https://www.resplendence.com/latencymon) and try to find out what might be wrong. The output of it is:

[image]

There seems to be a problem with my `HDAudBus.sys` and `wdf01000.sys`. Has anyone encountered similar issues and how I can resolve those? Is this a hardware or software problem?

Multiple errors found in Event Viewer:

```
- The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
- The server Microsoft.SkypeApp_15.64.80.0_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5c!App.AppXtwmqn4em5r5dpafgj4t4yyxgjfe0hr50.mca did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
- The previous system shutdown at 2:10:58 AM on ‎10/‎26/‎2020 was unexpected.
- The server {AB8902B4-09CA-4BB6-B78D-A8F59079A8D5} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
- Dump file creation failed due to error during dump creation.
- Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 : Has determined that the network adapter is not functioning properly.
- A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the sppsvc service.
- The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x0000001e (0xffffffffc0000094, 0xfffff8057cd9764d, 0xfffff608a99f61f8, 0xffffa38098ceb930). A dump was saved in: C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 805c74e4-3874-4499-8ffc-c036b8daf8ce.
- The Origin Web Helper Service service failed to start due to the following error: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

**(26-11-2020)** Brand new error:

```
Initialization failed because the driver device could not be created. Use the string "000000000100320000000000D71000C013010000250200C000000000000000000000000000000000" to identify the interface for which initialization failed. It represents the MAC address of the failed interface or the  Globally Unique Interface Identifier (GUID) if NetBT was unable to  map from GUID to MAC address. If neither the MAC address nor the GUID were  available, the string represents a cluster device name.
```

Comment: Please post some `.dmp` files from folder `C:\Windows\Minidump` on an online service such as OneDrive or Dropbox. Use 7Zip or Zip to compress these files.

Comment: @harrymc I could only find two dumps in that folder: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VM4jU0WC8DbRe-Je1eUnSt8fwyusYHOq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: (1) In `112220-106171-01.dmp` the problem is in driver `stornvme.sys` with error code
STATUS_INTEGER_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO. Do you have an NVMe disk? (2) On `100720-153000-01.dmp` the error is INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR with an undocumented error code, maybe connected to power problem. (3) Did a Windows update happen recently? (4) Search for errors in the Event Viewer, (5) To check the hardware run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight.

Comment: (5) Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html), follow with the DISM command in the article, and if DISM finds anything run `sfc /scannow` again.

Comment: `1`  Yes, I do have a NVMe disk - Samsung 960 Evo 256GB. My Windows is located on it. `2` My laptop is always connected to its charger and most of the crashes happen while plugged in. Can that be an issue? `3` Yes, but I believe crashes started a few updates ago so I am really not sure which one might have caused it. `4` I will be updating the main question with the data from event viewer. `5` I will use that one tonight.

Comment: Last (5) should have been (6) ...

Comment: Just started `6`. I believe I did it before and there were no issues detected. I have also used Windows Memory Diagnostic tool and it did not detect any issues with memory. I will still run MemTest86 tonight.

Comment: Update on 6: `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`

Comment: @harrymc I have found multiple Error logs within Event viewer. I have updated the description above.

Comment: Horrible lot of errors. One error is for the Origin Web Helper Service service, which could be stopped and set to Startup type of Manual, but that won't solve everything. I'll wait for the results of MemTest86. I would add to the list: (7) Run deep antivirus tests, at least by Windows Defender and by Malwarebytes.

Comment: @harrymc `5` output of MemTest86 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V6xCqOwS1Lla0f0gtmq3fW4qopFwUtMT/view?usp=sharing All tests passed successfully. `7` I did run both Windows Defender and Malwarebytes tests. Malwarebytes detected some issues which I cleaned up and should be okay. I don't think these were in any way connected to my issues though. Could you recommend what the next steps would be to resolve these errors from above?

Comment: On the assumption that something is wrong with Windows, I would suggest doing [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), which is the same as doing a major upgrade of Windows, so to be done with the same precautions.

Comment: As for the error reported for the WiFi adapter, [this](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Intel-R-Wireless-AC-9560-160MHz-Has-determined-that-the-network/td-p/726968) suggests you need a Windows 10 update from your 1903. I am not certain you are seeing the same problem a sin that post.

Given that an Update is something you might want to avoid, you could try something prior to it (it would take you a couple of hours): 
Setup a live USB with Linux, where you install a Win 10 VM. You can use that as a testbed.

Comment: @harrymc @sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio I believe the issue might've been caused by the SSD. I wiped my laptop completely and installed a fresh version of Windows. The SSD is detected during say the first 30 minutes of usage and then just becomes unavailable. Running `dskchk` results in `DSKCHK is not available for RAW drives.`. Rebooting fixes this for a short period and then it happens again. I tried formatiing it multiple times. Still results in the same error. Any ideas if I can somehow test it to be 100% sure it is the cause? I tried running CrystalDiskMark to evaluate it.

Comment: CrystalDiskMark started running the tests and midway it just stopped. Speeds were no longer showing and they all remained at 0 until the end of the process.

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms:

- All software tests have passed
- All disk tests have problems
- A reboot only helps for a short while
- Even a new install of Windows does not help

Conclusion: The disk is dead and needs to be replaced.
(I had this suspicion already, but full testing was required before giving
such an answer.)

Comment: I wanted to test the laptop before confirming on the thread here. I have now installed my Windows on another SSD. I still have not plugged out the faulty one since I wanted to make sure. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Today I got a brand new error. Not sure how this might be connected. The error is in the updated question above

Comment: Ensure that the faulty SSD is fully disconnected. If problems still arrive then it looks like there are more damaged component(s). Did you have a power surge?

Comment: I will be disconnecting it and use the PC for an extended period again. It happened during playing a game. No power surges.